# How to see Word Track Changes in Google Docs/without Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, google-docs

I don't have a local install of Microsoft Word, but I'm getting writing feedback in the form of .docx files with track changes on. Ideally, I would like to see the tracked changes in Google Docs, but I haven't been able to find a way to do that. I would prefer not to have to dive into the XML, but I'll do it if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not used Google Docs. Have you tried Word Online?
It is free. Here is a link. You will be able to see the tracked changes when in Reading View.
[Microsoft Word Online](https://office.live.com/start/Word.aspx)

Here is a description of the [differences between using Word Online (browser) and the Desktop Application](https://support.office.com/client/Differences-between-using-a-document-in-the-browser-and-in-Word-3E863CE3-E82C-4211-8F97-5B33C36C55F8?NS=WDWAENDUSER&Version=16&AppVer=WAW150&CorrelationId=6be226bc-c894-4058-97a9-4b6e3e9563a1#__toc304841573).